# Correct way to represent a while loop with one task in BPMN?

Tags: bpmn

Which is the correct~er way in BPMN to represent a simple while loop that redirects to one task only?

[image]

Comment: Yes, i'm agree with Antonie. The upper model is preferable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that using the loop activity is the better option as it helps keep the process model tidy.

Also be careful when creating loop in a process as usually task definition change between the first iteration and the second. e.g. first iteration is creation of a file, second will actually be an edition of the file: two different actions (create and edit) should not be in a single task definition.

Comment: Thank you, my thoughts the same, just needed confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the BPMN represents activities marching through time in a linear fashion similar to a Value Stream Map. To create a backward loop would disrupt the timeline.