# Correct way to diagram a BPMN loop process with more than one condition

Tags: bpmn

Most of the examples of BPMN representing loop processes use the example of a single task with a single condition, such as the one in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42690641/correct-way-to-represent-a-while-loop-with-one-task-in-bpmn).

[image]

However, I am struggling a little bit to understand how you might do this for a task that has two conditions (which might also mean that it needs to be broken up into multiple tasks?).

The example I will provide is this:

A person needs to send a message to someone and make sure that it has been received (task 1) so they can move onto the next step (task 2). But if they send the same message out three times with no response then they will take another action (task 3). So the two conditions for task 1 is that a confirmation has been provided by the receiver (condition A) and that the message has not been sent out three times yet (condition B).

[image]

Hopefully someone with more experience can help with an example or a better way to represent this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend *not* to model the repeated sending of messages as a loop. This is not an actual part of the business process, but probably rather a general communcation strategy in your system (and therefore valid for all sending operations).

If you do want to emphazize this behavior at this point, you could use an annotation.

So something like this should be fine and understandable:

[image: BPMN Example]

Comment: this was something that I didn't quite understand about the BPMN in how to deal with communication strategies that may or may not be part of the business process. But your answer gives a nice way to break down the task and make a decision instead of the loop task.